# Find Solution to an infinite Nested Radicals

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, nested-radicals

How do I find the solution to the following:
$$ \sqrt{ 7 - \sqrt{\frac{7}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{7}{4} - \sqrt{\frac{7}{16} + \sqrt{\frac{7}{256} - \ldots}}}}}$$
I first tried looking for a pattern for the denominators, but the $16$ seems to be throwing me off. Can we use calculus in this maybe, to find limits or something?

Comment: The denominators look like $2^{2^n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1:**
$$X = \sqrt{7 - \dfrac{A}{\sqrt{2}}}$$
where $A = \displaystyle\sqrt{7 + \sqrt{7 - \sqrt{7 + \sqrt{7 - ....}}}}$

**Hint 2:**
 $$(A^{2} - 7)^{2} = 7 - A$$

Comment: If $(A^{2} - 7)^{2} = 7 - A$ then $(A^{2} - 7)(A+7) = -1$ so $0 = A^3+7A^2-7A-48$. $A\approx 2.6260$.

Comment: @martycohen Nice. Exactly what I would have done. But I wanted OP to figure it out from the hints.